# Updating an s3 object generated by an Athena query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

My scenario is the following: I have many Athena queries I want to run.

For EACH of the Athena queries: I want the query results to be stored in a unique s3 path as a CSV.

Each time a query is run, I want the latest query results at a given s3 path easily identifiable. So for example, lets say query1 with `query-id-123` runs and completes successfully. I specify the s3 output path for query 1 to be `s3://mybucket/query1dataset/`. Then, a file will be produced at this location with the query results. Filename will be the query id, so the full path of the query results of query1 will be: `s3://mybucket/query1dataset/query-id-123.csv`.

Now, lets say I run query1 again. It will produce different results (because the input data in query1 has changed). This new execution of query1 will have a new query id, lets say `query-id-456`. I want these new, updated query results to be stored at the SAME path `s3://mybucket/query1dataset/`. So therefore when I search this path I want to find `s3://mybucket/query1dataset/query-id-456.csv`.

So I want to have the latest query results at a given s3 path.

The catch is, I only want to update the dataset at this path, if the query was successful. Consider the following:

- I delete the object at `s3://mybucket/query1dataset/`
- I run the Athena query1 to output results at `s3://mybucket/query1dataset/`, but the query fails.
- I've lost the previous version of my data.

One way I can think of getting around this is by writing to an intermediate s3 bucket location first. Then, if the query was successful, I would delete the object currently at the s3 path in the FINAL output bucket (`s3://mybucket/query1dataset/`), then I would copy the file from intermediate to final. The problem with this approach is that if the delete succeeds, but the copy fails, I've still lost my data. Also, HOW I do the copy is important. Apparently, s3 `cp` is atomic, but runs into issues if the file is large. If someone is doing a multi-part download from s3, they could end up with half new half old data https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2321.

Another approach I've thought of is always writing directly to the final output s3 bucket. However, with this approach, I am not sure how to tell what is the latest file at that path. I know you can sort by last modified time, but if the number of objects at a path exceeds 1000, I don't think that would work. A user would have to pull all object keys at that path into memory, then sort by last modified time to get the key, then query s3 again. That's unnecessary work.

How can I reliably and transactionally "update" the data at a static s3 path when the data is generated by an Athena query?

Comment: I think you are 'pushing the boundaries' of what can be achieved in Amazon Athena alone. You might consider implementing a tool such as [dbt](https://www.getdbt.com/) that can progress data through various transformation queries and can also perform 'tests' that stop that data flow if there are any problems with the transformation steps. This is especially useful since you have "many Athena queries" to run because dbt can schedule queries and transformations and understands the interrelationships between data (eg which queries should run before other queries).